# Using django-nose and django-celery together -- unit testing

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-nose

I have a django project that used [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose).  I'd like to add [django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/unit-testing.html) to the project.  I use unit tests.  Both django-nose and django-celery need a TEST_RUNNER setting in my settings.py file.  Specifically:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

for django-nose and:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'djcelery.contrib.test_runner.CeleryTestSuiteRunner'
```

for django-celery.

How should I handle this so that I can use both packages?

Comment: +1 idk, maybe have to subclass one and add the functionality of the other to your own class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the best way to handle this is to skip the Celery test runner.  I just use decorate my celery-using tests with a `@override_settings(CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)` and everything gets tested nicely.

Answer (score 4):

If you're able to isolate your tests into celery and non-celery dependent functionality, you could try [overriding settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#overriding-settings) on the test classes that invoke celery tasks:

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings

@override_settings(TEST_RUNNER='djcelery.contrib.test_runner.CeleryTestSuiteRunner')
class AsyncTestCase(TestCase):
     def test_async(self):
         self.assertEquals(add.delay(4,4), 8)
```

while the NoseTestRunner would be set as the default in settings.py

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass Celery runner and Nose runner, then you get good sides for all of them.

```
from django_nose import NoseTestSuiteRunner
from djcelery.contrib.test_runner import CeleryTestSuiteRunner

class TestRunner(CeleryTestSuiteRunner, NoseTestSuiteRunner):
    pass
```

Then in your settings:

```
TEST_RUNNER = '<package to>.TestRunner'
```

Why it works:

```
help(TestRunner)
```

You get:

```
|  Method resolution order:
|      TestRunner
|      djcelery.contrib.test_runner.CeleryTestSuiteRunner
|      django_nose.runner.NoseTestSuiteRunner
|      django_nose.runner.BasicNoseRunner
|      django_nose.runner.BaseRunner
|      django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner
|      builtins.object
```

The test CeleryTestRunner did nothing just setting some config and then call `super().setup_test_environment()`. Then the super will looking for setup_test_environment() in that chain.

Watch the video from Raymond Hettinger: super considered super([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo)).